# AngularJS mock - same service, different functions for unit test using jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to test a service A, this services has some functions:

Application code:

```
angular.module('app').factory('ServiceA', function() {
    var ServiceA = {
        _retryItem: null,

        retryItem: function(type, data) {
            ServiceA._retryItem = {
                type: type,
                data: data
            };

            return this;
        },

        clear: function() {
            ServiceA._retryItem = null;

            return this;
        },

        start: function(options, retryFn) {
            ServiceA.clear();
            ServiceA.retryItem('action', {url: '/my-url', options: options, retryFn: retryFn});
        }
    };

    return ServiceA;
});
```

Let's say I want to test the function "start", I have two options:

1) Call the real functions clear and retryItem:

```
...    

describe('...', function() {
        var options, retryFn;

        beforeEach(function() {
            options = {};
            retryFn = function() {};
        });

        it('...', function() {
            ServiceA.start(options, retryFn);

            expect(ServiceA._retryItem).toEqual({type: 'action', data:  {url: '/my-url', options: options, retryFn: retryFn});

        });
    });
```

2) Mock both functions clear and retryItem:

```
...    

describe('...', function() {
        var options, retryFn;

        beforeEach(function() {
            options = {};
            retryFn = function() {};

            spyOn(ServiceA, 'clear');
            spyOn(ServiceA, 'retryItem');
        });

        it('...', function() {
            ServiceA.start(options, retryFn);

            expect(ServiceA.clear).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(ServiceA.retryItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith('action', {url: '/my-url', options: options, retryFn: retryFn});
        });
    });
```

Which one is the correct way? What I understand from unit test - my unit is function "start", and everything else (functions clear and retryItem) I can mock and assume I have a test and is working, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends a little bit on what you want to test, how strict you are and personal preference. I would go for option two and test the remaining functions in other unit tests separately. That way you don't test stuff more than once, got some kind of documentation and can be sure, that these crucial functions are called with sound properties. For me, that sounds really good! :)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to ask what the function I am testing is doing. In this case, the start function is calling clear and retryItem. Those functions are the ones that are actually doing the work, all start is doing is making sure those are called. I would recommend that your test for start, just checks that those other functions are called and then write tests specifically for clear and retyItem.

You can check that others functions are called using spyOn.

```
spyOn(ServiceA, 'retryItem');

ServiceA.start(options, retryFn);

expect(ServiceA.retryItem).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

You can also test that parameters you expect to be passed in have been:

```
expect(ServiceA.retryItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['Expected Parameter']);
```